# OpenVPN client not working

Tags: 14.10, openvpn

I more or less followed the guide [here](https://openvpn.net/index.php/open-source/documentation/howto.html).  I'm able to connect to the server, I see the `tun0` interface has an IP address in `ifconfig`, I can get off a ping or two before all traffic stops.  I know the server is good because it works perfectly from an android client.  `syslog` has a warning (not sure if this is causing the problem):

```
Apr  6 09:33:41 laptop NetworkManager[818]: <warn> /sys/devices/virtual/net/tun0: couldn't determine device driver; ignoring...
```

Same symptoms connecting from both terminal and via openvpn-network-manager.  I allowed IPv4 forwarding in `/etc/sysctl.conf`.  Not sure what else to try.

Client config file:

```
client
dev tun
proto udp
remote x.x.x.x 1194
resolv-retry infinite
nobind
persist-key
persist-tun
ca ca.crt
cert client2.crt
key client2.key
ns-cert-type server
comp-lzo
verb 3
```

Comment: I am having a near identical problem. Did you get some resolution?

Answer (score 1):

In my case, the network where the client was connecting from was a 192.168.1.* subnet and the server side network was setup the same. I changed the subnet of one to 192.168.25.* and it started working.